# How to center align button with an icon for materialize css?

Tags: materialize

I have this login form and I want to center align the button but I can't seem to align it perfectly. What's the best way to center align it?

```
<form class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s10 offset-s1">
            <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="last_name">Username</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s10 offset-s1">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6 offset-s4">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">
                Submit
                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Make your `div` containing the button the same width as your form inputs and then simply add the `center-align` class like so:

```html
<form class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s10 offset-s1">
            <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="last_name">Username</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s10 offset-s1">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- CHANGED THE DIV BELOW (Changed size to col s10 offset-s1 
        to match the divs above and added center-align -->
        <div class="col s10 offset-s1 center-align">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">
                Submit
                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the attribute `text-align: center;` to the button container.

To do so I've added a class and included the css in the code below.

```
<style>
    .center-text {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<form class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s10 offset-s1">
            <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="last_name">Username</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s10 offset-s1">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6 offset-s4 center-text">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">
                Submit
                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use 'center' class on that tag which you want to make center align.